# NVIDIA driver kills sound

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound

I have a PC with ASUS B450-I mo-bo and GTX1060. I have 2 sound devices - NVIDIA HDMI and AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller (ALC1220).
Using any distro with nouveau - sound works fine. I tried multiple, with pipewire as server as well.

Whenever I install the proprietary driver, the sound on matisse controller dies after several seconds of system startup. The sound is written to the device but no actual audio is played as if it is muted.

Sound is present if I keep pavucontrol open but that's not a solution. Also, if I change sound device to HDMI and back to matisse in settings, sound is back for couple of seconds, then dies again. I have no idea how can I fix it. Please, help me. Disabling HDMI sound card has no effect.

Comment: It sounds like the audio is switching to use the nvidia hdmi device audio instead of the one you actually have connected to your speakers.

Comment: @user10489 I manually change the device but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-remove-nvidia-hdmi-audio-output-in-pulseaudio/

It says to delete user settings, or check add virtual output device in PulseAudio under Simultaneous Output.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work out.